# Why can't we use van-Kampen's theorem directly on the Hawaiian earring?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

The Hawaiian earring is the space 
$$X = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{(x,y) : (x-1/i)^2+y^2=1/i^2\}.$$

It is different from wedge of infinite circles.

But why can't we apply van Kampen's directly by taking each open path connected set to be
$$U_i = X\backslash\{(2/j,0)\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}^{j\neq i}$$

and hence obtain that 
$$ \pi_1(X,(0,0)) = *_{\infty}\mathbb{Z} $$ ?
Am I missing some detail?

Comment: Those sets are not open; the point $(0,0)$ does not have a neighbourhood in any of them.

Comment: I asked the exact problem several months ago. [Go check it out.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1827486/191404)

Comment: @MeesdeVries Oh right! Any neighborhood around (0,0) contains all but finitely many circles.