# Using van-Kampen's on Hawaiian ring.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, recursion, fundamental-groups

(On a related note, see this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943470/why-cant-we-use-van-kampens-theorem-directly-on-the-hawaiian-earring). )

The Hawaiian earring is the space $$X = \cup_{i=1}^{\infty}\{(x,y) : (x-1/i)^2+y^2=1/i^2\}.$$

It is different from wedge of infinite circles.

Set $U_i = X\backslash\{(2/i,0)\}$. For each  $i$, $U_i$ deformation retracts to a space that is homeomorphic to $X$. Moreover, $\cap_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i$ deformation retracts to $(0,0)$. Using van-Kampen's, we write

$$\pi_1(X,(0,0)) = *_{\infty}\pi_1(X,(0,0)). $$

Do such recursions make sense in group theory?
Can we conclude from the above recursion anything about Hawaiian ring's fundamental group? For instance, that it is uncountable?

Comment: The isomorphism are perfectly sensible, but it doesn't uniquely specify the Hawaiian ring's fundamental group. For example, it is also true of (in your notation) $*_\infty\mathbb Z$ -- which makes sense, because that is the fundamental group of a wedge countably many circles, for which the same argument holds.

Comment: @MeesdeVries That was fast! So in no way, we can construct $U_i$'s to use van-Kampen's on Hawaiian ring?

Comment: I don't know, but I don't think so. Otherwise it would be pretty easy to find, and I recall reading it's pretty hard.

Comment: Thanks. I came across this link [ https://wildtopology.wordpress.com/2013/11/23/the-hawaiian-earring/ ] which computes the fundamental group of Hawaiian ring. But I have not learnt the concepts that occur after showing that it is uncountable.

Comment: What is the point of using Van-kampen, any small open nbd of the origin again contain a copy of it-self, and you cannot get a good partition which satisfies that theor intersection is non-empty.